# Out put stream with dynamic location value/ file name?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

How to output a stream into a location that is getting dynamically..

For location getting statically can use

OUTPUT stream s1 to "D:\reports1.txt".

but if I want to get the value from screen, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DEF VAR cFileName AS CHAR NO-UNDO INITIAL "c:\temp\Bongo.txt".

DEF STREAM s1.

UPDATE cFileName FORMAT "x(30)".

OUTPUT STREAM s1 TO VALUE(cFileName).

OUTPUT STREAM s1 CLOSE.

Comment: I was looking for this type key word OUTPUT STREAM s1 TO VALUE(cFileName). thank you it is helpful....

Comment: You might want to take a peek at the documentation.  It is actually quite good at answering questions like this.